# Issue with iPhone XMPPFramework / Openfire

Tags: objective-c, ios, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

We have developed an app using Objective C XMPPFramework. However we notice that after a while the user goes offline. This is happening from a phone with iOS 4.x

We have made sure that Openfire has settings which allows clients to be idle and it also sends ping message to the clients. However, we are unable to understand why the user is going offline.

Please let us know if anyone has faced and resolved the same issue. Will be glad to provide more information if required.

Regards
Anup

Comment: Did you check the server logs? Is there any specific packet received from client before the logout?

Comment: Have you tried using XMPPReconnect to reconnect after accidental disconnects?

Answer (score 1):

`XMPPStream` has a property called `keepAliveInterval`. The default value is `120.0` (2 minutes) for an iPhone target. You might need to set that (e.g. in the same place where you initialize the stream).

If your server is actually sending [XEP-0199](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0199.html) pings, you might need to use `XMPPAutoPing` or `XMPPPing`.